# Closure-Compiler externs for AngularJS ui-router

Tags: angularjs, google-closure-compiler, google-closure, angular-ui

Are there closure compiler externs available for AngularJS's [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)?

Is there an appropriate place to ask for these from the closure compiler (or Angular-ui) team?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Old question, but useful (i hope) for people who until yesterday (like me) had looking for this resource. Check this out:

https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/master/contrib/externs/angular_ui_router.js

A kindly guy just released the UI Router externs. I havent tested yet, but i'm on it in this moment. I keep you posted about my findings.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the angular team. Externs are best when provided and maintained by the library author otherwise they are always out of date.